# ArrayList calls clear() ahead of time?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm just testing a SQL result set pagination method here but every time I try to add data from `c` to `b`, b ends up empty because somehow `c`'s clear function is called before it is added to `b` then sent back to the main class. I thought it may have been an initialization error but I've tested it and found it to be related to `c.clear()`, removing this allows the data to be added to `b` but won't clear `c` for the next 7 or less items. Why is this clearing before or how can I ensure it doesn't clear till the end?

(Clarification: Each result set's columns are saved as an ArrayList, representing one row of data. Then that is wrapped around another array representing the entire result set which is sent here to this method to be split into pages of 7 rows and send back into a hashmap for later retrieval.)

*This is just a test, not looking for perfection here*

```
public static void Index(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> raw, String user) {       
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> b = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> c = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    int n = 0;

    for (ArrayList<String> a : raw) {
        if (n < 6 && a.size() > 1) {
            c.add(a);
            n++;
        } else if (a.size() == 1) {
            c.add(a);
            b.add(c);
            c.clear();
        } else {
            n = 0;
            b.add(c);
            c.clear();
        }
    }

    n = 0;
    Clarify.results.put(user, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> somehow c's clear function is called before it is added to b

Java only have primitive and reference variable.
`a` and `b` and `c` are just references to objects.  When you add a reference to a collection and then alter the data that reference point to, you alter the one and only copy of that object.

In short, you can't add an object to a List, you can only add a *reference* to that object to a list.

Instead of calling `c.clear()` try creating a new list instead of clearing the old one.

```
// create a new list instead of altering the one we just added
c = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Or said another way: `add()` does not copy the value.

Comment: @Andreas it is better to think of the value being the reference to the object, in which case it copies only that.